Why this template example compiles using MSVC and Clang but not gcc
I was working on a CRTP based implementation. My solution needs to support all environments, therefore all compilers. The example below is not my real implementation, but gives you an idea of what I was facing. Please see the compiler explorer link for your discretion https://compiler-explorer.com/z/jfjha6c4s
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    void callDerivedFunction() {
        static_cast<Derived&>(*this).template templateMethod<double>(); 
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void templateMethod() {
        std::cout << "Template method called with type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }

    template <>
    void templateMethod<double>() {
        std::cout << "Explicit Template method called with type: " << typeid(double).name() << std::endl;
    }

    template <>
    void templateMethod<int>() {
        std::cout << "Explicit Template method called with type: " << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derivedObject;
    
    derivedObject.callDerivedFunction();

    return 0;
}

Gcc prints:
<source>:19:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Derived'
   19 |     template <>
      |               ^
<source>:20:10: error: template-id 'templateMethod<double>' in declaration of primary template
   20 |     void templateMethod<double>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Derived'
   24 |     template <>
      |               ^
<source>:25:10: error: template-id 'templateMethod<int>' in declaration of primary template
   25 |     void templateMethod<int>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:25:10: error: 'void Derived::templateMethod()' cannot be overloaded with 'void Derived::templateMethod()'
<source>:20:10: note: previous declaration 'void Derived::templateMethod()'
   20 |     void templateMethod<double>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:19:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Derived'
   19 |     template <>
      |               ^
<source>:20:10: error: template-id 'templateMethod<double>' in declaration of primary template
   20 |     void templateMethod<double>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Derived'
   24 |     template <>
      |               ^
<source>:25:10: error: template-id 'templateMethod<int>' in declaration of primary template
   25 |     void templateMethod<int>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:25:10: error: 'void Derived::templateMethod()' cannot be overloaded with 'void Derived::templateMethod()'
<source>:20:10: note: previous declaration 'void Derived::templateMethod()'
   20 |     void templateMethod<double>() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1


The complete verbatim errors should be posted in the question in a code block for keeping their formats.

Looks like if constexpr will be the solution to your issue

CRTP here is just a distraction. I can repro issue without CRTP.

Looks like some silly gcc limitation. Just moving implementation of template outside of Foo scope resolves the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/WGaPM7ev1
